# audio group switcher not shown on Plyr.io with HLS video audio

Tags: plyr, hls.js

I'm using the latest version of Hls.js & plyr.io .
**HLS have two audio language but audio switcher does not shown in plyr.io player.**

**master.m3u8** :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",LANGUAGE="es",NAME="lang Spanish",AUTOSELECT=YES, DEFAULT=YES,URI="a0_es/list.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="audio",LANGUAGE="en",NAME="lang English",AUTOSELECT=NO,  DEFAULT=NO,URI="a0_en/list.m3u8"
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=10000,RESOLUTION=426x240,AUDIO="audio"
v0_240p/list.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=420000,RESOLUTION=640x360,AUDIO="audio"
v0_360p/list.m3u8
```

**Script in page** :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const source = 'https://example.com/1500-x-xd12c26417dbf0a4523762ee558c221be/master.m3u8';
    const video = document.querySelector('video');
    
    // For more options see: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/#options
    // captions.update is required for captions to work with hls.js
    const player = new Plyr(video, {captions: {active: true, update: true, language: 'en'}});
    
    if (!Hls.isSupported()) {
        video.src = source;
    } else {
        // For more Hls.js options, see https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js
        const hls = new Hls();
        hls.loadSource(source);
        hls.attachMedia(video);
        window.hls = hls;
        
        // Handle changing captions
        player.on('languagechange', () => {
            // Caption support is still flaky. See: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr/issues/994
            setTimeout(() => hls.subtitleTrack = player.currentTrack, 50);
        });
    }
    
    // Expose player so it can be used from the console
    window.player = player;
});
```

**JavaScript libraries** :

```
https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js
dist/plyr.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest
```

**Note :** Audio group can be shown in video.js without problem.